# Printing a dictionary of lists as a single line

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists as shown below.

```
>>> my_dict
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

I want to print all the values in a single line like this.

```
a123b456
```

I was able to do this.

```
>>> print(''.join('{0}{1}'.format(x,y) for x,y in my_dict.iteritems()))
a[1, 2, 3]b[4, 5, 6]
```

and this

```
>>> print(''.join('{0}{1}{2}'.format(x,y,z) for x,y in my_dict.iteritems() for z in y))
a[1, 2, 3]1a[1, 2, 3]2a[1, 2, 3]3b[4, 5, 6]4b[4, 5, 6]5b[4, 5, 6]6
```

And this

```
>>> print(''.join('{0}{1}'.format(x,y) for x,z in my_dict.iteritems() for y in z))
a1a2a3b4b5b6
```

There is one condition though, I want to print with a single line without using strings or using nested loops. I do know that this single line itself is a nested loop.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please read the question completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches come to my mind:

1. generate a single list containing the string representations of all (*key*, *value*) pairs of the dictionary:

   > ['a123', 'b456']
2. generate a single (flat) list containing all keys and value lists:

   > ['a', '1', '2', '3', 'b', '4', '5', '6']

In both cases the final string can be generated by concatenating all the list items.

Below are a couple of possible implementations:

1. - `print ''.join(''.join(map(str, [k]+v)) for k,v in d.iteritems())`
   - `print ''.join(str(k)+''.join(map(str, v)) for k,v in d.iteritems())`
   - `print ''.join('%s%s' % (k, ''.join(map(str, v))) for k,v in d.iteritems())`
2. - `print ''.join(map(str, sum(([k]+v for k,v in d.iteritems()), [])))`

Comment: That sure helped. I was trying workarounds for quite some time.

Comment: Of course in my implementations `d` is the dictionary you called `my_dict`.

Answer (score 2):

```
print ''.join([''.join((k, ''.join([str(x) for x in v]))) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()])
```

Grab each (key, value) pair of items from the dictionary.
First, join the string representations of the value list (e.g. '123').
Then join the key to that (e.g. 'a123').
Finally, the outer **join** concatenates all the strings for the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot! That helped. I was almost there. Just missing out on the outer join.

Comment: Glad to help.  By the way, be careful of that term.  ""Outer join" is a common data base operation.  :-)